# Magento : Add Additional Tag in Header After Content is Rendered

Tags: magento-1, custom, header

I'm trying to add some data in header of page. When I try to do that, I am getting this error.

> Call to a member function getLastPageNumber() on null error

I am using same method for pagination on same page. 
Is there any way to append values in header somewhere in code after this function is no more null?

Comment: can explain more about of your desire requirement with code snapshot.

Comment: Can share the code, which you try to add in header.